# Applescript and javascript document.querySelectorAll click on a link

Tags: applescript, javascript, click

I'm trying to click on the ViewMYMachines link,
I'm not sure how to proceed, I suppose I have to use document.querySelectorAll

here is the link :

```
 <a data-auto-test-id="ViewMYMachines" href="/MYObjects/MYSupport.woo/ww/fsFSFSfdgdghHG/8.5.6.3.4.60.1">View</a>
```

here is my code

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell tab 1 of window 1 to set clickOnTheLink to execute javascript "document.querySelectorAll('data-auto-test-id= > a')[0].click();"
end tell
```

Comment: I can found some element with "document.querySelector("td > a");" and eventually I'm sure I can get to what I want using a different index, but then I won't always work as the index might change (the index could be different regarding the page I'm loading)